# What happen when 'unable to resolve host' still exist on terminal?

Tags: command-line, dns, hosts

After editing etc/hosts and hostname, 'unable to resolve host' still exist on my terminal, 
I still don't know what is the cause. Although my computer and my terminal runs so well. I'm only using single OS Ubuntu 12.04.1

[image]

[image]

[image][image][image]

Comment: Could you please post an example of what you type and the response you get? Also, adding more tags can broaden the viewership of your question to solicit more answers. I added dns for you just now.

Comment: did you reboot?

Comment: Yes, I did a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

To change the active system hostname to, e.g., 'foo' it does not suffice to edit /etc/hostname. You have to reboot or run `sudo hostname foo`. Also make sure that there is a line in /etc/hosts for 'foo', either

```
127.0.1.1 foo
```

if foo has no network connectivity or gets an address via DHCP, or

```
<IP-address> foo
```

if foo has a *static* IP address.

Comment: I followed your instruction., then reboot. I have an internet connection. But, "unable to resolve host" still there.

Comment: Please show the content of your /etc/nsswitch.conf file too.

Comment: Contents of my /etc/nsswitch.conf file are now attached on the description above.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that you have selected a hostname with a capital letter. It's conventional to use all-lower-case hostnames. Try making the host name "precise" with a lower-case pee. (However, I tried changing the name of my machine to a name starting with a capital letter and didn't encounter a problem with sudo. YMMV.)

Comment: Ok, I will try.

Comment: Still doesn't work, and I've got notification. Please see attachment above.

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /etc/nsswitch.conf /etc/hosts`. What are the apparmor messages in question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7302/discussion-between-obetus-and-jdthood)

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 222 Jan 29 19:46 /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 480 Dec 23 05:56 /etc/nsswitch.conf